# 'protractor exited with code: 3 Use --force to continue' in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I'm using protractor with jasmine framework to run my automation scripts. The test is failing with the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
Warning: Tests failed, protractor exited with code: 3 Use --force to continue.
```

while trying to get attribute value of an element.
But, I'm able to perform clicks and verifyElementPresent kind of actions for the same web element..

Could any one please help me out of this how to overcome this error.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure you aren't actually out of memory? Also, could you give us an isolated example of the test code?